# embed html in foreign website

Tags: html

I would like to know if somebody knows a method to embed custom html in foreign websites.
Maybe there's a firefox extension or something like that (like stylish for example, but for html instead of css)

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow, but will require a lot more information if you want an answer.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "embed custom html in foreign websites"? What kind of website, and why do you want to do such thing? consider improving your question with more details.

Comment: @ChrisF: I think the question like it is now belongs here, but you are right if he would ask for a specific script or if he would have a problem with a specific script (and indeed give more information then), that it would belong on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, that's where the [Greasemonkey Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) is for. Once you have that installed, you can create scripts which manipulate the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) of any website you would like:

> Allows you to customize the way a
>   webpage displays using small bits of
>   JavaScript.
>
> Hundreds of scripts, for a wide
>   variety of popular sites, are already
>   available at http://userscripts.org.
>
> You can write your own scripts, too.
>   Check out http://wiki.greasespot.net/
>   to get started.

Also nice to know is the fact that the latest version of Chrome, and also Opera (don't know since when, but longer than Chrome) supports userscripts out of the box (no need to install any add-ons).